# How to implement a custom JavaFX control based on a Pane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am looking to implement a base, extendable custom control in JavaFX 8, comprising a pane with other controls added to it.

So, for example, it may comprise of a `GridPane` holding a `TextField`, a `Button` and a `CheckBox`.

I do not want to subclass `Pane` or `GridPane` because I do not want to expose those APIs to the user. So, "a node which is made up of a grid pane" as opposed to "a node which extends a grid pane".

I see that extending `Region` or `Control` is possible, which is recommended? What is required to delegate sizing and layout to the pane?

```
public class BasePaneControl extends Control {
    private final Pane pane;

    public BasePaneControl(Pane pane) {
        this.pane = pane;
        getChildren().add(pane);
    }

    // What do I need to delegate here to the pane to get sizing
    // to affect and be calculated by the pane?
}

public class MyControl extends BasePaneControl {
    private final GridPane gp = new GridPane();
    public MyControl() {
        super(gp);
        gp.add(new TextField(), 0, 0);
        gp.add(new CheckBox(), 0, 1);
        gp.add(new Button("Whatever"), 0, 2);
    }

    // some methods to manage how the control works.
}
```

I need help implementing `BasePaneControl` above please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend Region, and override the [layoutChildren](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layoutChildren--) method.

You can use the Region.snappedTopInset() method (and bottom, left and right) to get the position of BasePaneControl. Then calculate to position that you want your Pane based on other components that may be a part of BasePaneControl.

Once you know the location for the Pane, call [resizeRelocate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#resizeRelocate-double-double-double-double-).

```
/**
 * Invoked during the layout pass to layout this node and all its content.
 */
@Override protected void layoutChildren() {
    // dimensions of this region
    final double width = getWidth();
    final double height = getHeight();

    // coordinates for placing pane
    double top = snappedTopInset();
    double left = snappedLeftInset();
    double bottom = snappedBottomInset();
    double right = snappedRightInset();

    // adjust dimensions for pane based on any nodes that are part of BasePaneControl
    top += titleLabel.getHeight();
    left += someOtherNode.getWidth();

    // layout pane
    pane.resizeRelocate(left,top,width-left-right,height-top-bottom);
}
```